# C# tabcontrol file not found

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I have a problem that I don't understand. I have a tabcontrol with 2 tabs in it.

Tab 1: tab with datagridview in it

tab 2: tab with checklistbox in it

When I'm in the tab 2, I run this code without a problem:

```
foreach (int i in groupeCheckedListBox.CheckedIndices)
{
    groupeCheckedListBox.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Unchecked);
}
```

but if I'm in the tab 1, it doesn't find the checklistbox so I decided to write this code:

```
if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabControl1.TabPages[1])
{
    foreach (int i in groupeCheckedListBox.CheckedIndices)
    {
        groupeCheckedListBox.SetItemCheckState(i,CheckState.Unchecked);
    }
}
```

but when I run it, I receive an error:

> "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : 'Le fichier spécifié est introuvable'

which mean that it cannot find the file at the line "if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabControl1.TabPages[1])".

I also tried to go with:

```
tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages[1];
```

and

```
TabPage t = tabControl1.TabPages[0];
tabControl1.SelectTab(t);
```

with the same result.

Can someone explain me why it doesn't find the file please?

Comment: Read the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabpage?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks) section. The second **Note** box.

Comment: @dr.null Oh !  thats is interesting !  

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm tab controls in Winforms can be tricky, are you putting this logic in the SelectedIndexChanged event on the TabControl? Then you should be able to check the index value and determine which tabPage you have active and the controls in each tab should always be accessible and instantiated, I was able to check the selectedTab to the tabPage expected and it evaluated true:[image]

Comment: Hi, i tried it and it and i see my tabs no problem but the main problem is the same. I even tried to make him change tabs at load to be sure there is a selected tab and even if it did change, the problem remain the same. Dr. Null seems to send me to the answer tho ;)